Help controlling a second circuit with a 1.8 V output (solved!)
I have been making some custom retro gaming hardware at home and I can’t figure out a solution to this problem, I hope you guys can help me.
Basically in this PCB I have two LED outputs HL1 and HL2 both output 1.8 V (measured with multimeter) but the (- negative) of the HL1/HL2 is not connected directly to the ground of the USB/3V/3.7V sockets.
this PCB only uses USB to charge or to power it self it doesnt data via USB.
I have a lithium battery connected to the 3.7V socket.
I need to connect the "PED circuit 1" to HL1 which is basically a power booster DC-DC step up to 5V connected to my 2 LED lights, because they require 5V to operate.
But it wont work. It wont work directly, or with a resistor it always outputs the same 1.8 V best case scenario.
But the circuit works fine in the 3V socket, but it needs a resistor, 150 Ω works fine.
HL1 main function is to indicate the state of the board (standby, pairing, etc).
it blinks on pairing, turns off on standby, etc.
I want to power circuit1 using HL1 directly or using the 3 V socket but controlled by the HL1 socket with a transistor or a optocoupler acting as a switch or something.
thanks in advance!
EDIT1:
Unfortunally this is all the info i have on the board
ali express link
aditional notes:
i have a 150 ohm resistor in the input on the circuit1 because for some reason the PCB "shutsdown" if i dont use a resistor high enough and connected it to the HL1/2 socket or any 3V socket, which doesnt happen if i connect circuit1 without a resistor directly to a AA battery for example and it will work fine.
Thing is even with a resistor circuit1 in the HL1 it will always output 1.8v, due most likely the voltage been below 0,9v of the circuit 1 requirement, but in the 3v it outputs around 2v so it works fine.
with HL1 (or 2) ON

i measured 1,83v between the (+) and (-) of the HL1 socket.
so it checks out.
i measured 1,87v between the HL1(+) and the ground of the 3V socket
the (-) of the HL1 in not direct to the ground but its not a big difference anyways.. so i guess its fine.

with HL1 (or 2) OFF

I measured 3v (!!?) betweem the HL1(+) and the ground of the 3V socket and ALSO 3v between the HL1(-) and ground of the 3v socket
ok.. now im completely lost.

EDIT2:
Turns out circuit1 (step up 5v) is unnecessary, the main 5V LEDs still operate fine in the 3V range, it simplifies things.
aditional info:

i measured the resistance on HL1 pins while the PCB as NO POWER AT ALL, using the 2k ohm range on the multimeter or less, the PCB LED (that mimic HL1) will turn On, heh, i guess the current the multimeter injects is enough to power the onboard leds and closes the circuit.

EDIT3:
Problem solved.
Again thank you very much for the help!


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Give this a try. It assumes you have access to the USB's +5V, and also the +3V supply rail:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If you can't use the +5V available from USB, then you can still use the DC-DC boost converter, but power it permanently from the +3V supply:

simulate this circuit

yes i cant use the +5v usb pin. so i tried circuit 2 and works!
The Main 5V LED (D1) reflects the PCB state as it should.
blinks on pairing, turns off on sleep, etc.
However is just like you said, circuit 1 will drain the battery when the led is OFF.
if i remove circuit1 and output directly the 3V, R2 will still drain a little, but way less im guessing?
But if push comes to shove, ill implete a manual switch to cut the power of the battery and be done with it, but as long the D1 reflects the PCB state im good :)
Again, TYVM for the help!

It sounds like you are trying to source a switch mode power supply with a pin dedicated to driving an LED? And for some reason put a 150 Ohms in series on the input?
I don't know why you think this would work. My recommendation is to put a power rail on the boost converter's input (your 3.0 V or 3.7 V supply). And use your LED outputs HL1 and HL2 to drive the bases of a couple of transistors.

Connect the 5V output to a resistor, then to your LED, then to the transistor's collector.
Connect HL1 (or HL2) to a resistor, then to the base of the transistor.
Connect the emitter to ground.

I don't know what "mass/GND" is. If you can add some documentation or schematics of the board to your question, that would help.
Either way, you likely also need some capacitors (10+ uF?) between the converter's input and ground, and the output and ground.
Edit
Regarding your question updates:
I'm guessing HL1 and HL2 are inputs, not outputs. Are they the anodes and cathodes of the 2 LEDs that are already on the board? If so, you may need to deliver power to them. Or do you need to short the pins to provide a current path for the LEDs?
In the absence of any kinda of documentation, it's anyone's guess.
I would suggest removing your USB power, and measuring the resistance between the HL1 pins and each side of LED1. Do you get zero?

thank you for the help!
i added more info and clarified the main post.
the transistor switch would work, but after those measurements im not so sure anymore.
im curious, the capacitors are to prevent the leds from blinking?

@KlyzeJr Answer updated. Regarding the capacitors, no they are not to prevent anything from blinking. Most regulators, especially switch-mode, require bulk capacitors in order to work properly. Since yours is a module it may not be needed. But it may, and can't hurt.

i measured the resistance on HL1 while the PCB as NO POWER, >2k ohm range on the multimeter, the mainboard LED will turn On, heh, i guess the current the multimeter injects is enough to power them.
Another user gave me a transistor circuit that works, unfortunally it will drain the battery slowly.
I think on top of that ill add a manual off/on switch, its not ideal but it gets the job done, as long the main LED reflects the PCB state im good.
I updated and removed circuit1, turns out the main 5V LEDs also operate fine in the 3V range, simplifies things a little bit.
TYVM for the help!
